# Android: How do I get thumbnail from a Video (Uri)

Tags: android, android-thumbnail

I want thumbnail from a video at any specific position. I am using ThumbnailUtils in order to get thumbnail from video uri and assigning to bitmap but I am getting null value on bitmap.

Any reasons how this is happening and how do I fix this?

```
selectedVideoUri = data.getData();

bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getRealPathFromURI(videoUri),
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: This question is valid and still unanswered lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use Glide to load thumb directly to imageview

```
Glide.with(activity).load(videoPath).into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Load Video List with its path in Your array list using below method**

```
 private void loadData(String currentAppPath) {
    hiddenpath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + currentAppPath);
    String[] fileName = hiddenpath.list();
    try{

            for(String f : fileName){
                if(HelpperMethods.isVideo(f)){
                    videoFiles.add(hiddenpath.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+f);
                }
            }
            new Loader().loadImages(Environment.getExternalStorageState());

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

**You need Loader().loadImages method so i declare this method in separate class file. see below code**

```
public class Loader {
String[] imagieFiles;

public void loadImages(String path){

    Log.e("path",path);
    System.out.println(path);
}  }
```

**Then after You can use below Code to Get Video Thumbnail. By default Each Video Store two size Thumbnail.**

1) **MINI** -- MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND and

2) **MICRO** -- MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND

```
  Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(thumb);
            contentViewHolder.videoView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supported by Android natively using [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) [SeekTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#seekTo(long,%2520int)) method

If you just want to show the video placeholder to display then you can use below code:

```
video_view.setVideoPath(videoPath);
video_view.seekTo(3000); // in milliseconds i.e. 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

`ThumbnailUtils` returns `null` when file or video is corrupted.

but I wanted to only use `Uri` and this is a good solution to do this:

```
val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
mmr.setDataSource(videoUri)
val thummbnailBitmap = mmr.frameAtTime
imageView.setImageBitmap(thummbnailBitmap)
```