# Get a video thumbnail from uri to ImageView

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails, android-glide

**Hello guys,
How can I get a video thumbnail from uri and display it in ImageView(recyclerView).
I have tried the following:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(...){
Video video = videolist.get(position);
//Other methods...
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(video.getVideoUri,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnail.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
String result = bitmap.toString();
Glide.with(theContext).load(result).into(holder.imageview);
}
```

**And**

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(video.getVideoUri));
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(2000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
String result = bitmap.toString();
Glide.load(theContext).load(result).into(holder.imageview);
```

**But none of them is working.
Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: do you get any error ? and have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471196/175554 ?